# UWP app (Windows 10) submission failed with error code(s) 2003

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store

I have developed UWP app (Windows 10) that record user voice through microphone and upload the recording file to web server through API.

While trying to submit this app to windows app store, it gets rejected with error message: This submission failed with error code(s) 2003

I have generated the appakcage through VS2015 and its pass the Windows App Certification Kit

Comment: It's hard to detect the reason for your submission failure just according to this error code, which has not been included in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/resolve-submission-errors). You could post a comment below the article. The best practice is still to create a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account so that they can review your specific package.